# Intermittent database connection issues and errors following MariaDB upgrade in cPanel on Cloudlinux 7

Tags: mariadb, centos

I am experiencing intermittent database connection issues on my cPanel server running on CentOS 7, following an upgrade of MariaDB from version 10.5 to 10.6. Despite the upgrade process completing seemingly without issues, I have been encountering sporadic errors, particularly related to database connections, as evidenced in the MariaDB error log.

Here are

```
2023-10-11 20:13:30 0 [Note] Starting MariaDB 10.6.15-MariaDB source revision 0d16eb35bc981023ce2f4912e8ecde68ca381f4e as process 21694
2023-10-11 20:13:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.7
2023-10-11 20:13:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2023-10-11 20:13:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using crc32 + pclmulqdq instructions
2023-10-11 20:13:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2023-10-11 20:13:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 4294967296, chunk size = 134217728
2023-10-11 20:13:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2023-10-11 20:13:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segments are active.
2023-10-11 20:13:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2023-10-11 20:13:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2023-10-11 20:13:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2023-10-11 20:13:31 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.6.15 started; log sequence number 294287172131; transaction id 1816193214
2023-10-11 20:13:31 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2023-10-11 20:13:31 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2023-10-11 20:13:31 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
2023-10-11 20:13:31 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2023-10-11 20:13:31 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mariadbd: ready for connections.
Version: '10.6.15-MariaDB'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MariaDB Server
2023-10-11 20:13:39 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 231011 20:13:39
2023-10-11 20:30:03 4947 [Warning] Access denied for user 'Cpanel::MysqlUtils::Unprivileged'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
2023-10-11 21:00:03 12883 [Warning] Aborted connection 12883 to db: 'myplayli_wp602' user: 'myplayli_wp602' host: 'localhost' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2023-10-11 21:41:52 24436 [Warning] Aborted connection 24436 to db: 'aquae' user: 'aquae' host: 'localhost' (Got an error writing communication packets)
2023-10-11 21:53:43 27245 [Warning] Access denied for user 'senac'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
2023-10-11 22:11:13 32589 [Warning] Aborted connection 32589 to db: 'aquae' user: 'aquae' host: 'localhost' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2023-10-11 22:25:04 35817 [Warning] Access denied for user 'Cpanel::MysqlUtils::Unprivileged'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
2023-10-11 22:42:54 39399 [Warning] Aborted connection 39399 to db: 'myplayli_wp602' user: 'myplayli_wp602' host: 'localhost' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2023-10-11 23:18:29 47223 [Warning] Aborted connection 47223 to db: 'myplayli_wp602' user: 'myplayli_wp602' host: 'localhost' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2023-10-11 23:26:19 48866 [Warning] Aborted connection 48866 to db: 'cnaecuad_evoice2017' user: 'cnaecuad_evoice' host: 'localhost' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2023-10-11 23:26:22 48876 [Warning] Aborted connection 48876 to db: 'cnaecuad_evoice2017' user: 'cnaecuad_evoice' host: 'localhost' (Got an error writing communication packets)
2023-10-12  0:02:01 57080 [Warning] Access denied for user 'senac'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
2023-10-12  0:04:46 57718 [Warning] Access denied for user 'wp_aygss'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
2023-10-12  0:04:47 57727 [Warning] Access denied for user 'wp_ws2yt'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
2023-10-12  0:04:49 57731 [Warning] Access denied for user 'wp_cf2cc'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
2023-10-12  0:30:04 63153 [Warning] Access denied for user 'Cpanel::MysqlUtils::Unprivileged'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
2023-10-12  1:36:13 76590 [Warning] Aborted connection 76590 to db: 'sistegra_livechat3' user: 'livechat3' host: 'localhost' (Got an error writing communication packets)
2023-10-12  1:39:48 77256 [Warning] Aborted connection 77256 to db: 'sistegra_livechat3' user: 'livechat3' host: 'localhost' (Got an error writing communication packets)
2023-10-12  1:41:30 77537 [Warning] Aborted connection 77537 to db: 'sistegra_livechat3' user: 'livechat3' host: 'localhost' (Got an error writing communication packets)
2023-10-12  1:42:48 77756 [Warning] Aborted connection 77756 to db: 'sistegra_livechat3' user: 'livechat3' host: 'localhost' (Got an error writing communication packets)
2023-10-12  1:43:30 77878 [Warning] Aborted connection 77878 to db: 'sistegra_livechat3' user: 'livechat3' host: 'localhost' (Got an error writing communication packets)
2023-10-12  1:43:38 77915 [Warning] Aborted connection 77915 to db: 'myplayli_wp602' user: 'myplayli_wp602' host: 'localhost' (Got an error writing communication packets)
2023-10-12  2:42:12 88322 [Warning] Access denied for user 'Cpanel::MysqlUtils::Unprivileged'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
2023-10-12  4:06:06 103056 [Warning] Aborted connection 103056 to db: 'cnaecuad_evoice2017' user: 'cnaecuad_evoice' host: 'localhost' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2023-10-12  4:30:03 107495 [Warning] Access denied for user 'Cpanel::MysqlUtils::Unprivileged'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
2023-10-12  5:11:06 113979 [Warning] Access denied for user 'senac'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
2023-10-12  5:11:07 113983 [Warning] Access denied for user 'senac'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
2023-10-12  5:29:13 116099 [Warning] Access denied for user 'Cpanel::MysqlUtils::Unprivileged'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
2023-10-12  5:29:28 116116 [Warning] Aborted connection 116116 to db: 'sistegra_livechat3' user: 'livechat3' host: 'localhost' (Got an error writing communication packets)
2023-10-12  5:30:40 116238 [Warning] Access denied for user 'senac'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
2023-10-12  6:42:23 125628 [Warning] Access denied for user 'Cpanel::MysqlUtils::Unprivileged'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

Additional context:

The issue began after uninstalling MySQL Governor and upgrading MariaDB from 10.5 to 10.6 via WHM. All websites have correct database users and passwords configured. The errors are intermittent and do not consistently affect database connectivity.

I have verified network configurations, ensured that database user credentials are accurate, and checked that user privileges are correctly assigned. However, the issue persists.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue or can provide insights into potential solutions or troubleshooting steps to resolve these intermittent database connection issues?